# The XAML part of DataTemplateSelector for itemscontrol

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, itemscontrol, datatemplateselector

I'm using the MVVM model to create an app. In this app I wish to create some popup's which look different but use the same viewmodel. That is I wish to create a observable collection of the viewmodel, and then use these on the different views, so they'll use the same logic from the viewmodel, but will have different values for the data. So far I'm using the DataTemplateSelector, and I've created some code behind, but I'm kind of lost when I have to implement the xaml part into my itemscontrol to select the dataTemplate. So If anyone could help it would be appreceiated.

I've followed [this](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/06/multiple-item-templates-in-windows-phone.aspx) article so far.

Comment: You could explain in more details what you want to achieve. Screenshots or a more concrete example would suffice.

Comment: question is quite unclear . Will you please give details ?